# EXEC at remote server using paramaterized query

Tags: sql-server, ruby, jdbc, jruby

I am trying to run the following SQL on a Linked Server;

```
INSERT INTO dbo.test (FirstName, LastName)Values(?,?)
```

`dbo.test` exists on a linked server with an alias from the local SQL server of (`DATALOADER01`).

Therefore, the query I want to perform is;

```
EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.test (FirstName, LastName)Values(?,?)') AT [DATALOADER01]
```

Ruby code that is executing the SQL;

```
def connect(server, database)
    url = "jdbc:sqlserver://%s;databaseName=%s;integratedSecurity=true" % [server, database]
    return java.sql.DriverManager.get_connection(url)
end

    def execute_q(statement, options = [])
        @conn = connect('sql','master')
        ps = @conn.prepareStatement(statement)
        options.each_with_index do |opt, index|
            set_param(ps, index.to_i + 1, opt)  
        end
        ps.execute()
    end
```

There error I get is 'Index 1 is out of range'

The code works when I pass a non-paramterized query to `execute_q`. For example;

```
EXEC('CREATE TABLE dbo.test2 (Test nvarchar(max))') AT [DATALOADER01]
```

There are no permissions issues, and the links are setup correctly, so I am not concerned there are issues there.

I appreciate I can do an insert to a linked server without using `EXEC`, however `MERGE` statements do not work unless done this way.

Comment: Try `EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.test (FirstName, LastName)Values(?,?)', ?, ?) AT [DATALOADER01]`. You need to pass the parameters to the parametrized query you are executing.

Comment: Perfect, that works! Thanks!

Comment: Great, I wasn't 100% sure it would work, and I didn't have an SQL Server install at hand to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.test (FirstName, LastName)Values(?,?)') AT [DATALOADER01]
```

You are only asking SQL Server to forward the string `'INSERT INTO dbo.test (FirstName, LastName)Values(?,?)'` to the linked server. It does not know about the parameters. To be able to supply the parameters, you need to explicitly send them as part of the `exec` statement you are executing. So you need to use:

```
EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.test (FirstName, LastName)Values(?,?)', ?, ?) AT [DATALOADER01]
```

Here you add two parameters to the `exec` command, which then allows SQL Server to recognize you want to pass parameters.